# Failed to upload painting: Article must exist - opoloo

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, blogs

Is anyone using opoloo lines engine for their rails blogging framework?

If you have, did you encounter this error message `Failed to upload painting: Article must exist` while trying to upload pictures to your blog post? Otherwise, could someone explain the error message below in the server log, as I don't really know how to read it.

Cheers!

Server Log:

```
Started POST "/blog/admin/pictures" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-02 13:20:40 -0400
Processing by Lines::Admin::PicturesController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GJ9xrVC8lI0wL9Frg2/pczM8mUhIdLW6n/nKEcpkZcIQ29e49Jzr+IL+LQNSZPfhcxEORW3qIUPaazszCVfMrA==", "picture"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007faeaa9f2828 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/lm/ylf12v411cq8gtqzd5r8g1th0000gn/T/RackMultipart20180602-2100-je3ae9.jpg>, @original_filename="DSC08611.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[image]\"; filename=\"DSC08611.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}
  Lines::User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "lines_users".* FROM "lines_users" WHERE "lines_users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/lines-engine-1.2.3/app/views/lines/admin/pictures/create.js.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/lines-engine-1.2.3/app/views/lines/admin/pictures/create.js.erb (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1904ms (Views: 246.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Comment: The following lines `(0.1ms)  begin transaction`, `(0.1ms)  rollback transaction` is telling you that some validations were failed.

Comment: Thanks, @Mr.Y, is there a way to check which validation had failed?

Comment: @ttinggggg you can add a debugger in the `Lines::Admin::PicturesController#create` and see if there are any errors on the picture object `@picture_variable.errors` use

Comment: Thanks @Deepak Mahakale , how do I do that?

Comment: are you using any of these gems? `byebug`, `pry`, `debugger`

Comment: @ttinggggg the validation that failed is in your question, "Article must exist". You need to assign `article` to your `picture` object in `create` action before saving it.

Comment: @DeepakMahakale I have byebug

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Thanks. How can I do that on the web interface?

Comment: Alright guys, I cheated. I just went into my db browser and put my image there and it works. But I feel like I've to somehow fix it though.